# Not able to use the value of process.env.URI inside my db.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, uri, dotenv

I am using .env file to store mongodb uri but i am not able to use it inside my db.js. Here are the screenshots of code.
db.js
[db.js screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sIJRz.png)
.env
[.env screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7BOgH.png)

I am getting this error when i am executing this, instead of this i expect to get no error and connect with my mongodb database.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cENQ8.png)

Comment: Please copy your code into the question instead of using images. Use the Edit link and just paste it in as formatted code. [Here is why](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `uri` variable is `undefined` because you are creating it before you call the `config()` function so `process.env.URI` is not in scope yet. That's why your MongoDB connection error is being thrown.

Simply change the order or execution like so:

```js
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const uri = process.env.URI
```

.env

```bash
APPLES='{"name": "gala"}'
```

```
const dotenv = require('dotenv');
dotenv.config();
const apples = JSON.parse(process.env.APPLES);
console.log('apples=', apples.name);
// apples=gala
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It worked, do you know how to put a json file inside an env ? I want to make my firebase admin sdk a secret.

Comment: You should be able to store a JSON string and then use `JSON.parse(process.env.THE_STRING)`.

Comment: Could you give any references from somewhere? like what I have to write in .env and then in js.

Comment: Added an example

Answer (score 0):

Put the URL address in the .env file inside double quotes. Like the following code:

```
S3_BUCKET="YOURS3BUCKET"
```

and run the dotenv module as a single line before calling by process:

```
require("dotenv").config();
```